# How can I call a variable from another python file which is re-defined

Tags: python

in file1, value of "source" is changed depends on which button I click.

```
source = 0
form_class2 = uic.loadUiType("./UI/Code.ui")[0]
class Code(QDialog, form_class2):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.aa)
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.bb)

def aa(self):
    global source
    source = 1
    app.quit()
        
def bb(self):
    global source
    source = 2
    app.quit()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = Code()
    myWindow.show()
    app.exec_()

import file2
```

then in file2:

```
from file1 import source
print(source)
```

output is 0

How can I get 1 or 2 for the output in flie2?

Comment: Use `import file1` and call `file1.source`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you

```
from file1 import *
```